I want to check if query - select * from ignTestt1 exists in following input string (either using java substring or linux commands)
Note :  Query can be distributed in different patterns and on multiple lines having hexadecimals in between, so looking for a concrete solution
for eg. in another set, sel can be on first line, ect * fr on second line , om ignT on third line and estt1 on last line having its hexadecimals in between each lines
IPC: 00000030   ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00         ................
IPC: 00000040   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 73 65 6c 65         ............sele
IPC: 00000050   63 74 20 2a 20 66 72 6f 6d 20 69 67 6e 54 65 73         ct.*.from.ignTes
IPC: 00000060   74 31 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 01 00 02 80 00         t1..............

tried with awk,sed,grep commands but somehow didn't get exact command to execute

This is...doable, I suppose... but the permutations are daunting. Can you strip just the text output from all the hex dump columns? Do you know the exact string? If not, make sure you check case-insensitively, account for varying whitespace, and possibly other syntaxes like specified columns, including possible literals and/or embedded comments. Be aware that the hexdump dots are a visual conversion, but they mean you have to be especially careful with your metacharacters, too. (Is this an X/Y question?)

I would use awk to get the last column, combine them into a single line, then search for the string.

Why are you trying to search the output of a hex dump like this, rather than just capturing the original data and searching that?

Please [edit] your question and explain where the hex dump file comes from.

Assuming you have the binary file producing that dump, then
strings file

would produce
select * from ignTest1

